# add a node to a circular linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

i am trying to write a generic circular linked list class. i tried to add nodes to the make a circular linked list but the adding of the nodes is not quit working correctly.. The order of the nodes being added is not correct for some strange reason..

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import linear.Node;

public class CircularLinkedList<T> {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    private Node<T> rear;
    private static int size;

    public CircularLinkedList() {

        rear = null; 
        size = 0;

    }

    public void add(T data) {

        rear = new Node<T>(data, rear);

        size++;
    }
}

public class Node<T> { //generic node

    public T data;
    public Node<T> next;

    public Node(T data, Node<T> next) {

        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;       
    }

    public String toString() {

             return "" + data; //force concatation data.toString() is automatically called

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the class Node? There is a contradiction between Node<T> rear and new Node<T>(data, rear). What errors do you get?

Comment: i don't get any errors but the nodes are not correctly added.. i took the example 1 3 2 21. they added like tht but when i print the rear and rear.next i get 21 and 2 instead of 21 and 1

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please tag this with [homework].

Comment: no hw learning circular linked lists and how they work and how is this hw from wht point u think this hw atleast think before u say something..

Answer (score 1):

21 and 2 is the correct answer. `rear` is the first element of the linked list, and `rear.next` is the second element. Since you added 21 last, it's the first element, and since you added 2 second-to-last, it's the second element.

Were you expecting something different?

Answer (score 1):

By

```
rear = new Node<T>(data, rear);
```

you insert a node at the beginning of a linked list. The rear is pointing at the first node. Your problem is that the last node didn't point to the first node. I think it's better if you use 2 pointer here, one points to the beginning, and the other points to the end. And then, every time when you add a new node, not just let the first pointer point to the new node, but also let the end node points to the new beginning node.

```
private Node<T> head = null;
private Node<T> rear = null;
public void add(T data) {
    head = new Node<T>(data, head);
    if(rear == null)
        rear = head;
    rear.setNext(head);
    size++;
}
```

This solution also insert new node at the beginning of the list. If you want to insert new node at the end of the list, you should do this:

```
private Node<T> head = null;
private Node<T> rear = null;
public void add(T data) {
    Node<T> node = new Node<T>(data,head);
    if(head == null){
        head = node;
        node.setNext(head);
    }
    if(rear != null)
        rear.setNext(node);
    rear = node;
    size++;
}
```

Comment: where did u get the setnext method is it your implementation?

Comment: Yes, you should implement this.

Comment: how do i do that? can it be done using .next or that is completely different sorry i am new at data structures

Comment: Since you have "public Node<T> next;", therefore node.next will do. But generally, people use private and setter & getter.

Comment: i am getting a null pointer at rear.setNext(node); when i change it to  rear.next = node;

Comment: My mistake. The problem is when you insert the first node, rear is still null, so you cannot call rear.next. What I'm doing here is if there is any node pointed by rear, which means the list has some elements, we should let the last node point to the new added node, this is what rear.setNext(node) does. I added a if statement, when rear is null, which means there is no any element there, then we do not need any node to point to the newly added node cause we don't even have one.

Comment: i think my add method is fine the problem is how i print my list. it is now giving a null pointer would you mind looking at it?

Comment: Take your example 1 3 2 21, your add method produce a linked list (not a circular one) like this: rear -> 21 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 -> null . I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: exactly i don't want a linkedlist i want a circular linked list

Comment: The only difference between linked list and circular linked list is that linkedlist.rear.next == null && circularLinkedlist.rear.next == circularLinkedlist.head . Everytime when you insert at the head or the rear, you need to redo rear.setNext(). And the difference between insert at the head and insert at the rear is rear = node or head = node. The tricky is the order of pointer assignment and how are you going to deal with the null pointer when you insert the first one.